# Use @@RowCount for multiple updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Normally I have `usp_sp_Name_InsertOrUpdate` stored procedures

So my structure is simple as:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
     SET [Column] = @NewValue
     WHERE ...


    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO [TableName] ...
    END
```

To resume this, stored procedure looks for an update, if it does not update anything  `@@ROWCOUNT == 0`, so it proceed to `INSERT` statement if `@ROWCOUNT > 0` just stop there.

My question is. If I have more than one `UPDATE` statement like:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
         SET [Column] = @NewValue
         WHERE ...


    UPDATE [AnotherTableName]
         SET [Column] = @NewValue
         WHERE ...
```

If first update returns `@@ROWCOUNT > 0` but second one return `0` stored procedure continue with `INSERT` statement because `@@ROWCOUNT` only detects last `UPDATE` query.

Is there some trick to know if any update return `@@ROWCOUNT > 0` if it isn't the last one?

Comment: If you have multiple updates, you have to capture the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` after each statement. By design `@@ROWCOUNT`'s value is reassigned after every statement that effects a dataset.

Comment: Or build a solution using the [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause for full control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```sql
DECLARE @OLD_ROWCOUNT int; 

UPDATE [TableName]
         SET [Column] = @NewValue
         WHERE ...

SET @OLD_ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT  -- capture after the first UPDATE

    UPDATE [AnotherTableName]
         SET [Column] = @NewValue
         WHERE ...

-- now you could use @@OLD_ROWCOUNT
```